# Excel Javascript API - Record Date on Adjacent Cell

Tags: javascript, excel, api, office-js

I am new to Excel JavaScript.
I'm trying to record the date a cell changed in column 4 and update column 7 with the date & time the change occurred. I'm encountering parameter out of range whit the .getColumn statement. Hope someone gives me some guidance.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
 var s= workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  if(s.getName() =="Records"){
  var r = workbook.getActiveCell();
  if(r.getColumn(4)) {
      var nextCell = r.getOffsetRange(0, 3);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getColumn` is to get a column contained in the range.

You would need to use `range.columnIndex == 4`, please note columnIndex is Zero-indexed.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
 var s= workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  if(s.getName() =="Records"){
  var r = workbook.getActiveCell();
  r.load('columnIndex');
  await context.sync();

  if(r.columnIndex == 4) {
      var nextCell = r.getOffsetRange(0, 3);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());

  }
```